# Magical data get distinct and count?

Tags: ios, core-data, ios7, nsfetchedresultscontroller, magicalrecord

I'm try using magical record not succeeded . i have a entity like below

```
name | value
------------
mic  |  40
ada  |  30
bca  |  50 
mic  |  70
bca  |  32
mic  |  45
```

this is my entity i need result like that

```
mic - 3
ada - 1
bca - 2
```

how to do that in magical record.

Comment: You need to explain this more. What exactly do you need? What have you tried? What isn't working? What is it doing instead of what you want? etc...

Comment: @Fogmeister i try in distinct magical record but i got all record

Comment: Please post a snipped of your fetch request so we can see what you're trying in actual code.